# CMake and XCode - disable CMake ReRun and CMake PostBuild Rules default generation

Tags: xcode, dependencies, cmake

I want to disable the additional dependency check generated for an XCode project (and possibly also the CMake cache update verification), since this increase very very much the entire build time (about three times in my case). With Visual C++ is sufficient to set the flag

```
SET(CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION TRUE)
```

but in XCode it does not have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into a similar issue.  You don't have enough details to help me understand if they are exactly related, but here's what I found:

Problem re-generating files using Qt, apparently hard to debug.
http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=8833

This is the thread that started it all:
http://www.mail-archive.com/cmake@cmake.org/msg21149.html

Hope this  answer helps!
-dan